# simple-form not looking up i18n translations

Tags: internationalization, simple-form

`simple-form` is simply not looking up i18n translations. I was trying it on the placeholders.

simple_form.en.yml

```
en:
  simple_form:
    placeholders:
      company:
        name: "Company name"
```

The form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @company,
      url: company_path(@company) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

I've debugged using `i18n-debug`, and it didn't seem to attempt to look up

`en.simple_form.placeholders.company.name`

at all. Other non simple-form i18n lookups are triggering just fine.

Did I miss a step to 'turn on' i18n for simple-form? I thought it works right out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using `text_field` - a Rails form helper. Simple form supports it but it is not implemented in simple form (i.e. falls back to Rails). Change it to `f.input :name` and it should work.

Comment: Ahh. This should be listed in the common pitfalls when attempting to convert a form to simple form. Thanks!